# AngularJS $rootScope.$broadcast

Tags: angularjs

How to know `$broadcast` in AngularJS, have success response or unsuccess response

```
$rootScope.$broadcast($scope.abc + ':' + type + 'question', {
    abcSlug: $scope.abcSlug,
    questionSlug: questionSlug,
    abcObj: $scope.abcObj
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by _success response or unsuccess response_?

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast):

> $broadcast(name, args);
>
> Dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their
>   children) notifying the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners.
>
> The event life cycle starts at the scope on which $broadcast was
>   called. All listeners listening for name event on this scope get
>   notified. Afterwards, the event propagates to all direct and indirect
>   scopes of the current scope and calls all registered listeners along
>   the way. The event cannot be canceled.
>
> Any exception emitted from the listeners will be passed onto the
>   $exceptionHandler service.

So, the answer to your question:

> How to know $broadcast in AngularJS, have success response or
>   unsuccess response

is to catch exceptions